# How to automatically log in when displaying web with Flutter webview?

Tags: flutter, authentication, webview

As in the code above, url address is displayed as App using webview.
Is there a way to automatically log in?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: WebView(
              initialUrl: 'login page url',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _showNotification,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.access_alarms),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using cookie after the first login. I'm using flutter "CookieManager" to get parameter token from my webview url.